# Не отображается View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Работаю с nopcommerce. Создал `Controller, RouteProvider, View`. Пытаюсь вывести эту `View` на экран, но выдаёт PageNotFound. В чём может быть проблема?

RouteProvider:

```
namespace DevPartner.Nop.Plugin.Misc.Auction{
public partial class RouteProvider : IRouteProvider
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, new CustomViewEngine());

        routes.MapRoute("AuctionList",
            "auctions",
            new { controller = "Auction", action = "Auctions" },
            new[] { "DevPartner.Nop.Plugin.Misc.Auction.Controllers" }
        );
    }
    public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}}
```

Метод в контроллере:

```
public ActionResult Auctions(DateTime? date)
    {
        if (date == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Date = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            //here some logic 
            ViewBag.Date = date;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: да, я это уже поправил, сейчас тут поправлю. Ошибка таже

Comment: По какому URL вы обращаетесь к методу `Auctions`?

Comment: что за url такой `"auctions"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не мог зайти на страницу потому что плагин не был установлен. Зашёл в админку, установил плагин, всё заработало